# How pass a pointer to a pointer of byte array in C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I have to call from a C# application a C function (from a DLL) declared as:

```
void fillBuffer( uint8_t ** pData, uint32_t * size );
```

This function checks if `pData` is not null and in case it fills the buffer with some fancy data. The variable `size` it is used as input parameter to limit the number of bytes that will be written in `pData`, and as output parameter to inform how many bytes have been actually written.

In case `pData` is null, it will allocate the buffer itself and will *return* in `size` the number of bytes allocated.

How I can declare and call this function from a C# application (avoiding `unsafe` if possibile) in both *scenarios* (passing an already allocated buffer or letting it allocates for me)?

Comment: Declare an overload with `ref IntPtr` that passes `IntPtr.Zero`, and make sure you use the proper function to deallocate the returned memory later.

Comment: When you call a method data is stored on the execution stack and is not valid after you return from method.  So if your c++ is trying to return data as a pointer the data can be destroyed.  So you have to use one of three methods 1) Allocate the maximum size of the return data before calling the c++ method 2) Have c++ allocate the return data using the windows allocation method.  Then return pointer to allocated data.  You must remember to deallocate this data so you do not get memory leak 3) Call c++ and have the size returned only.  Then allocate size and call method again.

Comment: @jdweng You seem to be confusing [returning pointers to local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/11683) with returning pointers to memory allocated on the heap. The latter is a common pattern and is perfectly doable with C# + C as long as the C side tells you with what you need to deallocate the memory. An example is [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) that tells you to use [`LocalFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree).

Comment: @GSerg : I know what I'm saying.   You are just proposing my method 2 except instead of using the windows allocate method you are saying to use c++ heap.  Which is doable except c# cannot deallocate from the heap and would have to call c++ to do the deallocate.  While using Windows Allocation the c# can call the c# deallocate directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved using this solution:

```
...
UInt32 len;
IntPtr ppData = IntPtr.Zero;

fillBuffer( ref ppData, out len );
...
```

And declaring the function as following:

```
 [DllImport( "mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
 static extern void fillBuffer( ref IntPtr ppData,out UInt32 size );
```

Thank you

Comment: And how are you releasing the memory?

Comment: I have another C function that it is doing that. I am just providing it the pointer _returned_ in ppData.

Answer (score -2):

You cant call C functions without unsafe context. This is simply not possible. You cant use unsafe pointers in managed context unless you declared so.